# Going to a place possessive term

Tags: possessives

If I am going to a place named Coco (it's a bubble tea place), do I say I am going to Coco, or I am going to Coco's?

What is the use of the possessive term if it's a place?

Comment: *Coco's* means a place (usually a house or a restaurant) belonging to a person named Coco.

Answer (score 2):

Either can be used **colloquially,** particularly if Coco (in your example) is someone's name. It's fairly common in casual speech to call a place named *Tio Pepe* as "Pepe's," or a pub named *J. McCarthy* as "McCarthy's."

Answer (score 0):

*Coco's* would mean that the owner is named (or nicknamed) *Coco*.  If the shop's sign says only *Coco* or *Coco Bubble Tea*, then I'd say *to Coco*.

Answer (score 0):

If it's called *Coco's*, then you can just say, "I'm going to Coco's."
If it's called *Coco* and you want to say *Coco's*, then you should use a specifier, as in *Coco's place*, *Coco's restaurant* or *Coco's cafe*.